# Node.js: control the value of `this` when running a script with the `vm` module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I control the value of the top-level `this` variable when running a script with the `vm` module?

As far as I can tell:

- With `vm.runScriptIn(New)Context(…)`, the value of `this` is always `{}`.
- With `vm.runScriptInThisContext(…)`, the value of `this` is always `GLOBAL`.

Is it possible to control that value any further?

**Edit**: For example, just in case you don't trust me:

```
$ cat x.js
var vm = require("vm");
vm.runInNewContext("console.log('this:', this)", { foo: 42, console: console }));
$ node x.js
this: {}
```

**Edit 2**: In fact, it looks like `this` *is* set to the context, `console.log` just lies:

```
$ cat x2.js
var vm = require("vm");
vm.runInNewContext([
    "console.log('this:', this)",
    "for (var key in this) console.log('this has key:', key);",
    "console.log('this.foo:', this.foo);"
].join("\n"), { foo: 42, console: console }));
$ node x2.js
this: {}
this has key: foo
this has key: console
this has key: key
this.foo: 42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation for vm module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.7/api/vm.html#vm.runInNewContext)..

```
//this.hi in the vm becomes 'hello'
vm.runInNewContext(stuff, { hi: 'hello' });
```

Comment: Please note the first bullet point in my question: “With `vm.runScriptIn(New)Context(…)`, the value of `this` is always `{}`.”

Comment: OH WAIT. Node's `console.log` is just lying. You are correct. See my updated question.